# Exporting layer with Values set by Cascading Value Relations tables are converted to strings

Tags: qgis, valuerelation

I have cascading Value Relations tables for data entry and they work fine.  Except I need to "Export" the layer in order to keep the displayed values instead of the key values.  Except when I check the boxes that I want to hold the selected values for it changed the data type to string with a length of 254 no matter what the field parameters were set for initially.
[image]

[image]

These 3 strings were 10, 100 and 100 in Length initially.
If I had checked all the boxes it would have changed all my exported data to 254 character strings, even the integers!
Does anyone know what is going on here and how to avoid it?

Comment: What is a "cascading Value Relation"?

Comment: It is where you have hierarchy of selections depending on the value selected.  Response in Table A exposes possible appropriate selections within Table B etc. down the line until all your fields are satisfied.